# Updating a field in a serialized object blob

Tags: c#, sqlite, json.net

I am working on implementing a key-value persistence store for our application using `sqlite3`.

The `KeyValueTable` is created using the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE KeyValueTable ( ObjectName TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ObjectValue BLOB)
```

The API to `Get/Set` the key values has the following signature:

```
bool GetValue<T>(string key, out T value);
bool SetValue<T>(string key, T value);
```

So you can see that I can get and set the entire object using this API. For serialization, I am using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

Taking an example of the following class that is being store using the above APIs and serialization:

```
public class HistoryLog
{ 
  public string Data { get; set; }
  public long Id { get; set; }
  public long Sequence { get; set; }
  public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with my implementation is that every time I need to update the individual fields, I have to serialize the entire object and write it to the database.

Could there be a way to cache serialized objects and update individual fields as and when required and write to the database this cached serialized object?

This way I can save serialization everytime I need to update member fields.